# How do I add multiple elements to an array X times, based on a value from a second array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have two arrays, and both will be the same length.

```
let servers = ['Node1', 'Node2', 'Node3']
let counts = ['3', '4', '8']
```

I would like to create a new array, that has the first element repeated X times, with X being the number in the second array. The output should resemble something like this:

```
['Node1', 'Node1', 'Node1', 'Node2', 'Node2', 'Node2', 'Node2', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node3']
```

It has Node1 being repeated 3 times, Node2 being repeated 4 times, and Node3 being repeated 8 times.

Both arrays can be of varying length, and the servers can also be different names as well.

Here's what I've tried:

- Nested forEach of both arrays, but this just prints it at most 3 times, using the above example.

```
await response.servers.forEach(async (serverName) => {
    await response.counts.forEach(async (nodeNumber) => {
        let number = Number(nodeNumber);
        console.log(`serverName: ${serverName} | number: ${number}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop to loop over both arrays. Then use a nested loop to push the server name onto the result array the specified number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested for loop like this to iterate over each element in the first list, get it's position, find it's position in the second list, and repeat that many times. I made the second list ints which is better but you can convert it in the second for loop if needed by `Number(counts[i])`

```
let servers = ['Node1', 'Node2', 'Node3']; 
let counts = [3, 4, 8];
let newList  = [];

for (i = 0; i < servers.length; i++){
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < counts[i]; i2++){
        newList.push(servers[i])
    }

}

console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why to use `async/await` for this task, instead use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
let servers = ["Node1", "Node2", "Node3"];
let counts = ["3", "4", "8"];

const result = servers
  .map((s, index) => {
    const count = counts[index];
    const rep = Array(parseInt(count)).fill(s);
    return rep;
  })
  .flat();

console.log(result);
```

**for shorter syntax**

```js
let servers = ["Node1", "Node2", "Node3"];
let counts = ["3", "4", "8"];

const result = servers
  .map((s, index) => Array(parseInt(counts[index])).fill(s))
  .flat();

console.log(result);
```

**for One liner** using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let servers = ["Node1", "Node2", "Node3"];
let counts = ["3", "4", "8"];

const result = servers.flatMap((s, index) => Array(parseInt(counts[index])).fill(s));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tried to do too, just use two loops: one to read the number of repetitions and another to add the elements .. :)

```
var servers = ['Node1', 'Node2', 'Node3'];
var counts = ['3', '4', '8'];
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; counts[i]; i++){  // Retrieve the number of times the string will have to be repeated 
    for(var k = 0; k < counts[i]; k++) arr[arr.length] = servers[i]; // I add the elements to the new array 
}
console.log(arr); // I see the array
```